# Keeping original format POST passing through AWK

Tags: awk, whitespace, field

I have an issue with using AWK to simply remove a field from a stream, illustrated below:

```
  1 int blah (void)
  2 {
  3         if (foo) {
  4                 printf ("blah\n");
  5         }       
  6         return 0;
  7 }
```

I use the following code to remove the first field:

```bash
$ awk '{ $1=""; print }' example.out
```

```
 int blah (void)
 {
 if (foo) {
 printf ("blah\n");
 }
 return 0;
 }
```

Why is this the case? Is this because AWK removes all whitespace - can this be prevented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://awk.freeshell.org/RangeOfFields

Contains a description how to do it. It also links to http://student.northpark.edu/pemente/awk/awktail.txt which contains 3 solutions to the problem. As far as i know, if you assign to a field, then the output field separator is used to concatenate all fields together. So `" "+` suddendly is collapsed to one space. Take it with a grain of salt though, i'm no awk expert. For example, try assigning `:` to the variable `OFS`, and colons instead of spaces will result in between fields in the output:

```
echo a b c | awk 'BEGIN{ OFS = ":" } { $1=""; print }'
$ :b:c
```

If you use **g**awk, then you can use its `gensub` extension which i find pretty straight forward to use:

```
print gensub($1 "[\t ]*(.*)", "\\1", 1);
```