# Remove whitespace before a field using AWK

Tags: linux, formatting, awk, whitespace

(*Almost exact duplicate of [Keeping original format POST passing through AWK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408469/keeping-original-format-post-passing-through-awk) submitted by same person.*)

I have a simple question pertaining to **g**awk, illustrated below:

```
  1 int blah (void)
  2 {
  3         if (foo) {
  4                 printf ("blah\n");
  5         }       
  6         return 0;
  7 }
```

Using the following gawk code - using gensub() to maintain original formatting:

```
 gawk '{ print gensub($1, "\t", 1) }' ./sample_code.out

     int blah (void)
     {
             if (foo) {
                     printf ("blah\n");
             }       
             return 0;
     }
```

How can I use **g**awk or awk (maybe with regular expressions) to remove previous whitespace before field $1  **(^)**

Illustrated below:

```
 int blah (void)
 {
         if (foo) {
                 printf ("blah\n");
         }       
         return 0;
 }
```

Comment: $1 never contains whitespace. You example shows that you add whitespace but in the text, you say that you want to remove it. Please edit your question to make clear what you get and what you want to do.

Comment: He wants to remove the numbers, stripping all leading space while preserving the formatting

Comment: (At least that's my interpretation of the question :-) )

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions guys! :) Actually, please excess my lack of understanding - as I'm new to AWK. Vinko, is correct - Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, but in the knowledge that you'll always want to strip 3 spaces.

```
vinko@parrot:~$ cat foo.c
  1 int blah (void)
  2 {
  3         if (foo) {
  4                 printf ("blah\n");
  5         }
  6         return 0;
  7 }

vinko@parrot:~$ gawk '{ print gensub(/^   /,"",1,gensub($1, "", 1)) }' foo.c    
int blah (void)
{
        if (foo) {
                printf ("blah\n");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '{sub(/^[ \t]+/, ""); print}'
```

This is from the famous awk 1 liners list, can be found here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20090227054719/http://student.northpark.edu:80/pemente/awk/awk1line.txt

Answer (score 2):

This strikes me as being a case of 'wrong tool for the job'.  I'd use sed`:

```
sed 's/^[ <tab>]*//' sample.out
```

Now, if the problem is all about the inner-most details of `awk`, this may be no help; if the problem is to get spaces removed, it is quicker and (at least arguably) simpler.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, first of all, thanks for your answer. Yes - it's possible to use sed - but using this implementation, original formatting is removed